# Регулярное выражение .net

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .net

Всем привет
Задача ввод русских и английских букв, все остальные символы и буквы допустим украинского языка игнорируются
написал код

```
var regexOne = new Regex("[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]");
var regexTwoo = new Regex(@"[\W]");

if ((regexOne.IsMatch(text))&(!regexTwoo.IsMatch(text)))
{
    //some
}
```

все работает как задумано символы игнорирует, но если в строке есть буквы из украинского алфавита пропускает, что нужно исправить. заранее благодарю

Comment: Как-то смущает проверка переменной text. Вы точно только одну введенную с клавиатуры буквы проверяете?

Answer (score 2):

В движке regex в .net есть поддержка [именованных блоков юникода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks) и [вычитания блоков](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction).

Что позволяет переписать проверку как

```
var cyrillicOrLatinLetter = new Regex(@"^[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsCyrillic}-[\W\d_]]*$");

if (cyrillicOrLatinLetter.IsMatch(text))
{
    //some
}
```

Answer (score 0):

пропишите явно весь необходимый набор букв кириллицы (абвгд...)

Comment: вы имеете ввиду так
[АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя]

Comment: не помогло

Comment: я не совсем понимаю синтаксис .net, но кажется у вас написано следующее:
если ((текст содержит хоть что-то из перечисленного набора символов) и (текст не содержит неалфивитноцифровую фигню)) {...}

но под задачу отбросить укр. кириллицу это не подходит т.к. строка будет содержать символы подходящие под шаблон и несодержать неподходящие под второй.
я бы попробывал что-то типа
if (!($text =~ /[^a-zA-ZАаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя]/)) { ... }

Comment: [**http://lurkmore.to/_/1806#mws_upT1Sjm**][1]

[1]: http://lurkmore.to/_/1806#mws_upT1Sjm

Comment: кто что еще посоветует ?

Comment: О_О это песец. Так над регулярками еще никто не глумился.

Comment: Как бы можно просто задать флаги игнорирования регистра и работу с юникодом.